# show two different stacked column data in one chart canvasjs react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvasjs

I want two stacked column data in one chart using canvasjs like this:
[image]

I have currently done something like this with the options:
this achieves removing x axis and secondary y axis and showing two data together

```
{
        animationEnabled: true,
        options:{
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{ stacked:true}]
                }
        },
        axisY: {
            titleFontColor: "#4F81BC",
            lineColor: "#4F81BC",
            labelFontColor: "#4F81BC",
            tickColor: "#4F81BC",
            margin:24,
        },
        axisY2: {
            gridThickness: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            lineThickness: 0,
            margin:24,
            labelFormatter: function(){
            return " ";
            }  
          },
        axisX:{
            gridThickness: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            lineThickness: 0,
            margin:24,
            labelFormatter: function(){
            return " ";
            }
        },
        toolTip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            cursor:"pointer",
        },
        data: [{
            type: "stackedColumn",
            name: "Proven Oil Reserves (bn)",
            legendText: "Proven Oil Reserves",
            showInLegend: false, 
            dataPoints:[
                { y: 30.25 },
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "stackedColumn",  
            name: "Oil Production (million/day)",
            legendText: "Oil Production",
            showInLegend: false,
            dataPoints:[
                { y: 17.46 },
    
            ]
        },
                   {
            type: "stackedColumn",  
            name: "Oil Production (million/day)",
            legendText: "Oil Production",
            axisYType:"secondary",
            margin:10,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataPoints:[
                {  y: 10.46 },
    
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "stackedColumn",  
            name: "Oil Production (million/day)",
            legendText: "Oil Production",
            axisYType:"secondary",
            margin:10,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataPoints:[
                { y: 10.46 },
    
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
```

it produces the result like:
[image]

what I need is to

1. give margin between two datasets
2. able to label datasets with text over them as seen in the image above

Answer (score 2):

> give margin between two datasets

There will be gap between datapoints when the [x-values](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/x/) are different.

> able to label datasets with text over them as seen in the image above

You can use [indexlabels](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/indexlabel/). Please refer [CanvasJS Docs](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/labels-index-labels/) for more info / examples. Below is an working example.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  axisX:{
    gridThickness: 0,
    tickLength: 0,
    lineThickness: 0,
    labelFormatter: function(){
      return "";
    }
  },
  axisY: {
    includeZero: true,
    tickLength: 0,
    lineThickness: 0,
    gridColor: "#ddd",
    labelFormatter: function(e) {
      return "";
    }
  },
  toolTip: {
    shared: true
  },
  data: [{
    type: "stackedColumn",
    indexLabel: "RM xyz",
    indexLabelFontColor: "#fff",
    dataPoints: [
      { x: 1, y: 47, color: "#c63531" },
      { x: 2, y: 32, color: "#449fc7" }
    ]
  }, {
    type: "stackedColumn",
    indexLabel: "RM xyz",
    indexLabelFontColor: "#fff",
    dataPoints:[
      { x: 1, y: 32, color: "#bb8786" },
      { x: 2, y: 27, color: "#74ab3e" }
    ]
  }]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```